Excel addin loop with recalculation of spreadsheet but custom functions are #BUSY
I have written an Excel addin using typescript. The addin includes custom functions that are called in the spreadsheet. Included is a function that changes data in the spreadsheet, recalculates the spreadsheet and records results in a loop. The problem I am facing is that:
for (var i=0; i<maxI;i++) {
  // update data in spreadsheet
  context.workbook.application.calculate(Excel.CalculationType.full);
  // get results from spreadsheet

does not work because the custom functions remain #BUSY! and all of my results are #CALC! errors. I am assuming that this is because the addin is waiting for my loop to complete before responding to the custom function calls in the spreadsheet.
I rewrote the loop using the onCalculated event handler which works but is incredibly slow.
m_eventResult = context.workbook.worksheets.onCalculated.add(handleCalculation);

One of the odd things about this event handler is that it is sometimes called multiple times before the spreadsheet has actually completed calculating. I solve this problem using:
const summarySht = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Summary");
const valueRng = summarySht.getRange("Portfolio_Value").load("values");
await context.sync();
if (valueRng.values[0][0] == "#CALC!") {
  console.log("Did not complete calculation.");
  return;
}

in the event handler.

Is my assessment of the situation regarding the custom functions correct? If so, can I force them to calculate in my loop?
What is the best way to implement a loop like this?
If the event handler is the best solution can I prevent the event handler being called before the spreadsheet has finished calculating?
If the event handler is the best solution, is there a better way of checking whether the spreadsheet has finished calculating?

I have tried the following:

Use the original loop and switch from common runtime to separate javascript runtimes. This did not solve the issue.
I could imagine putting the custom functions in a separate addin might solve the problem. I am not sure that my understanding of the problem is correct and thus do not know whether this would solve it.
Rewrite the custom functions as lambda functions in Excel. This is doable, but the functions are complicated and thus the implementation as lambda functions is non-trivial.

